# Проблема с получением id? у pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, discord, discord.py, pymysql

В моем коде есть функция, с помощью которой я проверяю: есть ли id пользователя в данной базе данных, или нет. Теоретически, когда пользователь отправляет сообщение, бот проверяет айди участника в базе данных, и если его нет - он записывает его туда.

Проблема заключается в том, что при написании сообщения пользователем, который есть в бд, бот все равно пытается закинуть айди участника в бд, получая следующее:

`pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '418**********' for key 'users.PRIMARY'")`

Все бы ничего, но данное сообщение серьезно засоряет консоль при написании любого сообщения. Прошу помочь мне разобраться в данном недоразумении. Заранее спасибо!

Код:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    with db.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(f"select * from users where id = {ctx.author.id}")
        myresult = cur.fetchone()

    if ctx.author.id == myresult:
        pass
    else:
        if ctx.author.id == myresult:
            pass
        else:
            with db.cursor() as curs:
                sqladd = "INSERT INTO users (id, level, exp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
                valadd = (ctx.author.id, 1, 1)
                curs.execute(sqladd, valadd)
                db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchone` возвращает кортеж (англ. tuple). Так что проверка в таком виде, как сейчас у вас никогда не будет работать.

Нужно или брать элемент кортежа (а для этого нужно знать его индекс, а `*` может вернуть колонки в произвольном порядке, упрощенно говоря):

```
cur.execute(f"select id from users where id = {ctx.author.id}")
myresult = cur.fetchone()
if ctx.author.id == myresult[0]
   # нашли
else:
   # не нашли
```

Или так (`fetchone` вернет `None` если запрос ничего не вернул):

```
cur.execute(f"select id from users where id = {ctx.author.id}")
myresult = cur.fetchone()
if myresult is None:
   # не нашли
else:
   # нашли
```

Ну и еще, лучше не использовать манипуляции со строками, так как это [небезопасно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Запрос делайте со связываемыми переменными:

```
cur.execute("select id from users where id = %s", (ctx.author.id,))
```

Comment: Бла-а-агодарствую!